# MIGS VPC Integration E5000: Cannot form a matching secure hash based on the merchant's request using either of the two merchant's secrets

Tags: asp.net, api, payment-gateway, mastercard

I am using Migs Virtual Payment Client Integration and Using 2-Party (API method).

Error  : **E5000**: Cannot form a matching secure hash based on the merchant's request using either of the two merchant's secrets

In the Reference Guide it is Stated to use HMac Sha256 for Generating a SecureHash Parameter that is sent in the Request and MIGS will Decode that request accordingly.

**Questions :**

**a)** I want to know that the Request i am creating is proper or not (i.e All the Parameters which are passed are in correct order).

**b)** Also let me know that if i am missing Some Parameters to send in the Request to create SecureHash and in Final Request.

**c)** Also check the functions that are used for generating the **SecureHash** are proper or not.

Please let me know if i am doing some Mistake .

Below are the Related Details.

1) **Request to generate SecureHash** :"vpc_AccessCode=XXXXXXXX&vpc_Amount=100&vpc_CardExp=1810&vpc_CardNum=5313581000123430&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TC_2014712466141&vpc_Merchant=TESTMXXXXXXXX&vpc_OrderInfo=TC_2014712466141&vpc_Version=1"

2) Demo **SecureHashSecret** = "CD14026NOT5E91GG5D1MOM4972440CDE"

**3)** SECURE Hash generated from Above **Request** and **SecureHashSecret**

"CCD0D0113315403E375791E99AFA3F8906EE47C0ED6818464368420048DC541E"

**4)** **Test URL** : "https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcdps"

**5)** **Final Request to Send on above URL**

"vpc_AccessCode=XXXXXXXX&vpc_Amount=100&vpc_CardExp=1310&vpc_CardNum=5313581000123430&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_MerchTxnRef=TC_2014712466141&vpc_Merchant=TESTMXXXXXXXX&vpc_OrderInfo=TC_2014712466141&vpc_Version=1&vpc_SecureHash=CCD0D0113315403E375791E99AFA3F8906EE47C0ED6818464368420048DC541E&vpc_SecureHashType=SHA256"

**6)** I am using the Below Code For Sending the Request and Getting the Response.

System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();

```
        webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        byte[] response = webClient.UploadData(hfVirtualPaymentClientURL.Value.Trim(), "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequest));



        string responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response, 0, response.Length);
```

**7)** **Functions** used  to Generate **SecureHash**

public static string ToHMACSHA256(string input, string key)

```
{

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);

    byte[] inputBytes = encoding.GetBytes(input);

    HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);

    byte[] hashmessage;

    hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes); 

    return ByteToString(hashmessage);

}
```

private static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)

```
{

    string sbinary = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
      { 
          sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); // hex format
      }

    return (sbinary);

}
```

Please get me the Solutions for the Above Error Asap. Thanks in Advance

Thanks & Regards

Sunny Pathai

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue?

Comment: no still there is Problem

Comment: Deny [Uncheck] the "Enforce Secure Hash" Setting from the Account to by pass the Hashing.    and use the Latest Test Cards. old Test cards are not working

Comment: I am getting the same issue, have you resolved the issue ? I am trying to do using python and there is no any document is available to refer for changing md5 to sha256

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same issue in `PHP`, but I successfully correct it.
The error seems to occurred because of an error while hashing my datas.
=> see [capturing error messages from migs payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728281/capturing-error-messages-from-migs-payment)

To correct the issue, I use these class 
https://github.com/Tmeister/banamexgateway/blob/master/VPCPaymentConnection.php
(and you have to import this one too to in your lib https://github.com/Tmeister/banamexgateway/blob/master/PaymentCodesHelper.php)

```
$conn = new VPCPaymentConnection();
$secureSecret = '';
// Set the Secure Hash Secret used by the VPC connection object
$conn->setSecureSecret($secureSecret);
// Instanciate your VPC post data
$paymentdata = array(
    "vpc_AccessCode" => '',
    "vpc_Amount" => '',
    "vpc_Command" => '',
    "vpc_Locale" => '',
    "vpc_MerchTxnRef" => '',
    "vpc_Merchant" => '',
    "vpc_OrderInfo" =>'',
    "vpc_ReturnURL" => '',
    "vpc_Version" => ''
);
// Add VPC post data to the Digital Order
foreach ($paymentdata as $key => $value) {
    $conn->addDigitalOrderField($key, $value);
}
// Obtain a one-way hash of the Digital Order data and add this to the Digital Order
$secureHash = $conn->hashAllFields();
$conn->addDigitalOrderField("vpc_SecureHash", $secureHash);
$conn->addDigitalOrderField("vpc_SecureHashType", "SHA256");
// Obtain the redirection URL and redirect the web browser
$link_to_mastercard = $conn->getDigitalOrder('https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay');
```

Answer (score 0):

Deny [Uncheck] the "Enforce Secure Hash" Setting from the Account to by pass the Hashing. and use the Latest Test Cards. old Test cards are not working

Comment: This can be a security risk as the purpose of checking the secure hash is to validate the "digital signature".